# What is this type of problem called?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I've looked in my book and all over the internet trying to make sense of problems like this:

$\sin(\arctan(\frac{3}{4}))$

What is this type of problem called? I don't know what to search for.

Comment: $\operatorname{arctan}(3/4)$ is equal to $\theta$ such that $3/4 = \operatorname{tan} \theta$

Comment: That helps actually, do you know what its called though? I want to find more examples of problems like this for practice.

Comment: Try Googling "sin(arctan(3/4))". . . it gives plenty of hits and I should think some of them would be helpful.  As far as I know there is no specific name for this kind of problem.

Comment: I've found examples but it's hard to piece the info together.

Comment: I don't know of a name for this exact type of problem, but it appears when inverse trigonometric functions are first introduced; you could just google them.  (For example, you'd find [these examples](http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATT8/inversetrig2.htm) with explanations which might help.

Comment: Thank you, that is an extremely helpful resource.

Comment: You might get useful hits under SOH CAH TOA.

Answer (score 2):

"involving trig and inverse trig functions" generates a few hits.

what you need to do to solve problems like these is to translate the trig function into a form that cancels easily with the inverse trig function. For you example, you need to express the $\sin$ in terms of $\tan$s so that you get a bunch of $\tan(arctan(3/4))$ in your expression.

For your example, here's what I would do
$$\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$
$$\tan x = \sin x\sec x$$
$$\tan x = \sin x\sqrt{\tan^2 x+1}$$
$$\sin x = \frac{\tan x}{\sqrt{\tan^2 x+1}}$$
Now we have an identity, we apply it to the problem
$$\sin(\arctan 3/4)=\frac{\tan (\arctan 3/4)}{\sqrt{\tan^2 (\arctan 3/4)+1}}=\frac{3/4}{\sqrt{(3/4)^2+1}}=3/5$$

Answer (score 0):

The name for this kind of problem is a trigonometric function using the inverse of $\tan$ in the form of $\arctan$.